# Why lord Shiva, lord Vishnu, and lord Brahma are less spoken in the Vedas as compared to devatās?

Tags: vedas, trinity

There are many shokas in the Vedas about devtas but there are few verses about trimurty (Shiva, Vishnu, and Brahma).

But what is the reason behind it.

Comment: Btw, it's spelled "Brahmā". Bhrama means confusion.

Comment: @Ikshvaku thanks for the correction